# React + gsap = why render when cursor moves?

Tags: reactjs, gsap

I made a custom cursor using gsap in react. I can’t understand why the rendering occurs when the cursor moves, although I don't change state?

[SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-bash-ykd2d)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

React Components by default don't skip render by shallow compare props and state, so every state update will trigger re-render.

You either need to implement `shouldComponentUpdate`, or extends `PureComponent`, or convert to Functional Component (which by default don't re-render if state doesn't change even if you call set state)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try with a hook. But I don't understand, why React.Component thinks need re-render when changed only css transform...

Comment: As far as I know, it may have performance impact if every React Component does shallow compare of each field of props/state to check for re-render, that's why you'd have to opt-in to this behaviour via `shouldComponentUpdate` or extends `PureComponent`. Functional Component auto opt-in this behaviour because each field of the state can be separated in its own hooks, so React doesn't need to loop through and shallow compare on each field of the component state.

Comment: Well, but the problem was setState (), it turns out I called the render several times myself, fixed it with a condition.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

[image]

### Solution 2

Don't use state but just variables ))